# SolidJS setStore is Applying to All Properties Rather than only the Specified Path

Tags: callback, store, solid-js

First time asking a question here so please be gentle.

I'm attempting to set a specific object within a store with a reference to a callback, but rather than only setting that specific object's callback, it's setting the callback for all objects along a similar path in the store.

Relevant function:

```js
const registerActionCallback = (
    on: 'Use' | 'Combo',
    actionName: string,
    cbKey: string,
    cb: (fns: ControllerActionFns) => void
) => {
    setState(
    'actionPool', // Record<string, Action>
    actionName, // string
    `on${on}Callbacks`, // Record<string, fn>, property of Action object
        cbKey,
        (_: (fns: ControllerActionFns) => void) => cb
    );
};
```

Example State:

```js
const [state, setState] = createStore({
    actionPool: {
        A: {...},
        ...,
        M: {
            ...,
            onUseCallbacks: {} // initially empty
            onComboCallbacks: {} // initially empty
            ...,
        },
        ...,
        Z: {...},
    },
    ...,
});
```

The idea is I have a series of 'actions' (buttons) that, when pressed, should run a series of callbacks that are located in either 'onUseCallbacks' or 'onComboCallbacks', which are objects to make deregistering convenient.

So, let's say I have actions A through Z, but I want to register callback 'testCB', which logs 'hello', with action M on Use.

The function will then run: `setState('actionPool', 'M', 'onUseCallbacks', 'testCB', () => () => console.log('hello'))`

The obvious expectation is that only clicking the button tied to action 'M' would log 'hello', except, clicking any button tied to any action in the actionPool A through Z will log 'hello'.

I can't for the life of me figure out what would be causing this so any insight would be greatly appreciated. Never experienced this issue despite using setStore in similar ways constantly, although this may be the first time I've tried setting callbacks using setStore.

**Edit:**

The way the callbacks are being called:
A reference to the pressed action is passed into a `fireAction` function which runs:

```js
for (const key in action.onUseCallbacks) 
    action.onUseCallbacks[key]();
```

**Edit 2 (fixed):**

Apparently, the issue had nothing to do with Solid. My janky prototype implementation for more conveniently generating the Action objects was assigning references to the same objects for onUseCallbacks and onComboCallbacks to all Action objects. One rewrite later and it's functioning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unnecessarily complex and does not look like an idiomatic Solid code but an attempt to create Redux like data flow.

Solid has its own execution model and does not have anything in common with React. It does not use VDOM and it does not re-render components upon state update. State can live anywhere, inside or outside a component. It is much more flexible and it has simple mental model.

That being said, it is best to cleanup and simplify your code.

Do you need a store? Probably not. A store is a reactive object or an array, depending on the initial value, wrapped in a proxy. Its API is simple and convenient. If you need an application wide object that needs to be accessible everywhere, you may need store, otherwise they are not needed.

Try to write your logic with primitives only, using signals and event handlers.

Comment: The purpose is to simulate patterns of action presses, so the state is located in a context that will be reused an arbitrary number of times for simultaneous simulations; keeping the relevant objects in a single store makes passing state around more convenient, as the consumers will need more than just the actionPool.
I don't really see how holding a record of Action objects in a state store is unnecessarily complex.

And certain side-effects with conditional existences need to add functionality to certain actions, hence registering callbacks.

How can I make this more idiomatic?